# Should I include colon in my msgid in PO file?

Tags: translation, localization, plugin-wpml, plugin-qtranslate, plugin-polylang

Which of the below is recommended when creating msgid a PO file?

msgid "Available Balance:"

or

msgid "Available Balance"

Comment: Does your code use `__( 'Available Balance:', 'my-plugin' )` or `__( 'Available Balance', 'my-plugin' )`? They're two different strings as far as the code is concerned. If you've got both, you should translate both.

Comment: @PatJ Yeah, I was hoping to do only `__( 'Available Balance', 'my-plugin' )` so I can use this for other purposes too,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of each depends on your choice. If, for example, the text is in front of a field, I think it is better to use the symbol:
In general, you should see if it really needs it or not. You do not have to use it or not. In the text you sent, the first option is more appropriate because the intention is to display a value in front of or below this text

Comment: I was thinking perhaps it's more convenient to use `Available Balance` since it can be used for other purposes. So that I don't have to have two almost identical keywords - one with `:` and one without. However, with that regard, I need to add a `:` in my PHP code.

Comment: @ratib90486 Yes, as our friend (Pat J) answered your question in the comment, it is better to make a language file in accordance with the php code. Of course, first create the php file and then easily add the translation file using poedit software.
It is always better to use: to display a value in front of the text or below the text